# Open URL in the New Tab : WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

When I uploads a image into the page using `Add Media`, I am setting url for that image, so that when user clicks on that image he should get redirect to another page. problem is, is get loading on same page.

I want it should get load in to another tab. I can't edit each href with `target="_blank"` as i have lots of images.

I just want to know is there any particular php file that should I edit or any other way is there.

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: why @metareviewr the question is not bad

Comment: @metareviewr  why ? is any wrong with my question?

Comment: You can do it with jquery. `jQuery('img').parent('a').attr("target", "_blank");`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(function(){ $("a img").attr("target","_blank"); });
</script>
```

Add this in `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to set `target="_blank"` for images:

1. Click an image to activate its settings pop-up window.
2. Click the Advanced Settings tab.
3. Scroll down to "Target" and you'll see the "open in a new window" checkbox there.

For old images, you'll have to make the change manually.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That will not be compliant in XHTML 1.0 Strict.

Comment: @PHPglue but it is valid HTML5

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript `window.open()`, like:

```
function imgWin(win, winName, imgArray){
  var dot, hsh;
  for(var i=0,l=imgArray.length; i<l; i++){
    (function(i){
      dot = imgArray[i].lastIndexOf('.');
      hsh = imgArray[i].slice(0, dot);
      imgArray[i].onclick = function(){
        open(win+'#'+hsh, winName, 'resizable=1');
      }
    })(i);
  }
}
```

Then you could even get your images easily, like:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
imgWin('imgwin.php', 'My Images, imgs);
```

Note, that `window` is implicit, so you don`t actually need to write`window.open()`.`open()` will work fine, in this case.